# Twitter API with Media ID / Status update

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have the following code, which works well apart from one issue, which is attaching the media_id to the final status update post. The media id just seems to be ignored and the text status is uploaded only. There is no error codes being output on either media upload request or status post.

Any ideas?

```
<?php
$oauth_access_token ="YOUR TOKEN";
$oauth_access_token_secret ="YOUR TOKEN SECRET";
$consumer_key ="YOUR KEY";
$consumer_secret ="YOUR SECRET";

//twitter api urls
$URLS=array(
    "image"=>"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json",
    "status"=>"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json");

function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}

function makeRequest($postfields,$url){
    global $consumer_key;
    global $consumer_secret;
    global $oauth_access_token;
    global $oauth_access_token_secret;

    $oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                    'oauth_nonce' => time(),
                    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                    'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
                    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                    'oauth_version' => '1.0'
                    );


    $base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'POST', $oauth);
    $composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
    $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
    $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

    $header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
    $options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                      CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

    $feed = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
    $json = curl_exec($feed);
    curl_close($feed);

    return $json;
}


//Upload image to twitter and get media_id
    $file = file_get_contents(BASEPATH . '/images/myphoto.png');
    $postfields=array("media_data"=>base64_encode($file));

    $result=makeRequest($postfields,$URLS['image']);
    $imageresult=json_decode($result);
    $imageid=$imageresult->media_id;
    //output results
    print_r($imageresult);


//Send status update with media_id attached
    $postfields=array(
        "status"=>"test messsage with image",
        "media_ids"=>$imageid);

    //output results
    $result=makeRequest($postfields,$URLS['status']);
    $statusresult=json_decode($result);
    print_r($statusresult);
?>
```

The media upload output looks complete

```
stdClass Object
(
    [media_id] => 6.7933955975536E+17
    [media_id_string] => 679339559755358208
    [size] => 51719
    [expires_after_secs] => 86400
    [image] => stdClass Object
        (
            [image_type] => image/png
            [w] => 187
            [h] => 116
        )

)
```

Comment: Still not resolved this problem, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was with the windows hosting, it doesn't like certain curl requests in php as they don't always work. So I changed the hosting to Linux and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using media_id_string instead of media_id

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though a year late! I found the problem was with the windows hosting, it doesn't like certain curl requests in php as they don't always work. So I changed the hosting to Linux and it worked fine after that.